# Nautilus Folder Custom Icon syncronize

Tags: nautilus, icons, sync, dropbox

I have a series of photo directories that I synchronize between computers using Dropbox.

~/Dropbox/Pics/Album1

~/Dropbox/Pics/Album2

In each of these, I have assigned the folder to have a custom icon of one of the images in the sub directory.

On my laptop, which has the same Dropbox account, these icons do not appear.  Now I know that the icon data is stored in:

~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata

However, given it's the metadata for all files that nautilus has seen (even those not sync'd).  I don't believe the solution is as simple as syncing this folder as well.  The two separate machines will constantly be competing with each other to make sure this folder matches "itself."

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You might solve it by just "pushing" the metadata from one computer to other (avoiding a two way sync). Your main computer will "command" the settings, the other(s) will just read the custom metadata. Thats makes sense? if yes, I can go with a proper answer :)